# Printing only 3 td for row in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to print the value from database. the database contains the image URL.
I am retrieving the image url through php and printing it.

I have written this code to do so.

**code:**

```
<?php
            if(! $conn )
            {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }
                $sql = 'SELECT name,thumbnail,link  FROM courses';
                mysql_select_db($dbname);
                $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
            if(! $retval )
            {
                die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><a href='".$row['link']."' title='Click to see schedule'><img src='".$row['thumbnail']."'></a></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            mysql_close($conn);
        ?>
```

This code is retriving image `URL` and displaying images on table. But I want 3 images per row, now it is printing only 1 image per row.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your code to only open and close the row every third image. Try this:

```
$i = 0;        
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
{
    if($i == 0) {
        echo "<tr>";
    }
    echo "<td><a href='".$row['link']."' title='Click to see schedule'><img src='".$row['thumbnail']."'></a></td>";
    if(++$i == 3) {
        echo "</tr>";
        $i = 0;
    }
}
// To close any open rows at the end
if($i % 3 > 0) {
   echo "</tr>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$cc = 0;
//initially open table row
echo "<tr>"; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
{
    $cc++;
    echo sprintf(
        '<td><a href="%s" title="Click to see schedule"><img src="%s"></a></td>',
        $row['link'],
        $row['thumbnail']
    );
    //close tablerow and open new one every 3 rows
    if($cc % 3 == 0){
       echo "</tr><tr>";
    }

}
//close last table row
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: This way can leave an empty row at the end if there is a number of rows exactly divisible by 3.

Comment: If num_rows % 3 = 0 this will have 2 closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

this code prints data in 3 columns in a row. Please try

```
$cols=3; $col=0;

$vars  = "<table>";
$vars .= "<tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval)){
    $col++;
    $vars .= "<td>".$row['link']."</td>";

    if($col==$cols){
        $col=0;
        $vars .= "</tr><tr>";
    }
}

$vars  = "</tr>";
$vars .= "</table>";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the same as @MarkResølved and leaves an empty row a the end if number of rows is exactly divisible by number of columns.